# Need help with a step in the solution of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I found this exercise in [this pdf.](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Teaching_Learning/Integrate%20sec%20x.pdf) 
It is the proof of the 5th exercise

$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt {s^2-1}}ds $

Substitute s^2-1
 $ s^2-1 = u^2,  2s ds = 2u du \implies \frac{du}{s} = \frac{ds}{u} $
 $ = \frac{du + ds}{u+s} $ <- Where does this come from?

I have never seen that before

Then the integral becomes:

$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt {s^2-1}}ds = \int \frac{ds}{u} = \int \frac{d(s+u)}{s+u}$

And I understand the rest.

Comment: Is this common way to solve that integral? I'm not sure how to justify it, although it is true (as other people answered) if we just think them as fractions (which is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's ratio and proportions.

If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, then

$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$

---

---

If you need a proof,

As, $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$

$ad = bc$

Adding $ac$ on both sides,

$ad+ac = bc +ac$

$a(d+c) = c(a+b)$

or $$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$$

Similarly, $ad + bd = bc +bd$

$d(a+b) = b(c+d)$

$$\frac{b}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$$

So, $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$

Cross-multiplying the first two terms,$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{du}{s}=\dfrac{ds}{u}:=\lambda;$

$du=s\lambda; ds=u\lambda;$

$\dfrac{du+ds}{u+s}=\dfrac{\lambda u +\lambda s}{u+s}=$

$\lambda \dfrac{u+s}{u+s}=\lambda.$